# chart.js Multiple Axes Cambiar el color a varios puntos dependiendo del valor

Tags: php, javascript, chart.js

He intentado cambiar el color de varios puntos de mi gráfica creada con Chart.js pero no lo he conseguido. Lo que quiero es destacar en color **ROJO** los puntos que superen un valor dado. El color por defecto es el verde.

```
<div align='center'><canvas id='grafico' name='grafico' width='250vw' height='80vw'></canvas></div>
```

El codigo donde genero el grafico es el siguiente:

```
var ctx_gp = document.getElementById("grafico");
var chart_datlog = new Chart(ctx_gp, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels : ["18:21:00","18:26:00","18:31:00","18:36:00","18:41:00","18:46:00","18:51:00","18:56:00","19:01:00","19:06:00","19:11:00","19:16:00","19:21:00","19:26:00","19:31:00","19:36:00","19:41:00","19:46:00","19:51:00",
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: "Temperatura",
            yAxisID: 'A',
            data :[21.4,21.3,20.7,20.5,20.3,20.2,20.2,20.1,20,19.9,19.7,19.5,19.3,19.2,19,18.8,18.7,18.5,18.4,18.3],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,0.4)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            label: "Humedad",
            yAxisID: 'B',            
            data: [76.9,59.8,61.9,62.4,63,62.9,63.1,63.1,63.2,63.2,63.4,64.1,64.7,65.1,65.6,65.8,66.2,66.4,66.7,67],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#71B37C',
            pointBorderColor: '#71B37C',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
            pointHoverBorderColor: '#71B37C'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,                   
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'A',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'ºC'
                }
            }, {
                id: 'B',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'right',
            }]
        }
    }

});
```

Para cambiar el color de los puntos que cumplan la condicion, he creado esta funcion:

```
for (i = 1; i < chart_datlog.data.datasets[0].data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (chart_datlog.data.datasets[0].data[i] > 20) {
        chart_datlog.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor = "#ea042a";
        chart_datlog.data.datasets[0].pointRadius = 5;
        chart_datlog.update(); 
    } 
}
```

Lo unico que consigo es cambiar todos los puntos al mismo color (rojo), y lo que yo quiero cambiar son los puntos cuyo valor sea mayor de **20**

Gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido el resultado que quería, incluyendo una función de control para **pointBackgroundColor**:

```
datasets: [{
    type: 'line',
    label: "Temperatura",
    yAxisID: 'A',
    data :[21.4,21.3,20.7,20.5,20.3,20.2,20.2,20.1,20,19.9,19.7,19.5,19.3,19.2,19,18.8,18.7,18.5,18.4,18.3],
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
    borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
    pointBackgroundColor: function(context) {
        var index = context.dataIndex;
        var value = context.dataset.data[index];
        if (value > 20) {
            return 'red'                    
        }
    },
    hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,0.4)'],
    borderWidth: 1
```